# Combobox in extjs doesn't respond to mouse events

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4.2

http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthradix/nwNte/2/

I have a filterContainer that have two combo boxes which should filter the grid data when I type or select using mouse. keyup events are working, but, when I use mouse to select, the grid data is not changing.

This is the snippet from the fiddle that creates comboboxes.

I tried adding additional events in checkChangeEvents list apart from the defaults which didn't work.

```
var filterContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
        border: false,
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 2
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            store: jsonStore,
            queryMode: 'local',
            fieldLabel: 'Company',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            labelSeparator : '',
            displayField: 'company',
            valueField: 'company',
            rowspan: 1,
            style: 'padding:0 15px 10px 0',
            checkChangeEvents : ['change', 'input', 'textInput', 'keyup', 'dragdrop','keydown','select']
            }, 
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: jsonStore,
                queryMode: 'local',
                fieldLabel: 'Price',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                labelSeparator : '',
                displayField: 'price',
                valueField: 'price',
                rowspan: 1,
                style: 'padding:0 15px 10px 0'
            }]
        });
```

Could you suggest what should I do so that combobox responds to mouse events?

Comment: why do you have the keyup listener in the textfield of a grid column and not on the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Do you listen to `change` event? If so, listen also to `select` event (same logic) because `change` is fired only on combo blur after selecting a value with mouse.

Comment: Do I need to write listeners for select and change events? What should I do after that?

Comment: You already have one keyup listener, just execute the same function on select listener.